# Meteor submiting form: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property'vk' of undefined

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

i'm using accounts-vk for providing login through vkontakte.ru
All works perfectly before i'm deleted meteor-autopublish package.
My connectSubmit.js:

```
    Template.connectSubmit.events({
        'submit form': function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var query = {
                vk_id: Meteor.user().services.vk.id,
                user_id: Meteor.userId(),
                photo: Meteor.user().services.vk.photo          
            };
        query._id = Connects.insert(query);
        Router.go('index');
    }
  });
```

Error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'vk' of undefined
```

And second problem with my template:
This worked good before i'm delete autopublish:

```
{{currentUser.services.vk.first_name}}
```

But now not working.
I'm think problem with Meteor.publish function, but i'm have no idea how to resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `autopublish` is on, it will publish **all** of your user's fields. When you remove `autopublish` only a few fields are published (username, _id, emails, profile).

If you publish the `services` field, you are exposing things like login tokens and hashed passwords to the client. Obviously, you never want to do that in production (which is why `autopublish` should always be removed). For more on this, see the "published secrets" section of my [common mistakes](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes) article.

So the short answer to your question is that the client shouldn't be doing any of these things in the first place.

The long answer is that if you have logic which requires these data, you'll need to do one of two things (which may warrant separate questions):

**if the services info is only needed for data mutation**

Use a server-side method in this case. In your `submit` event you would call a method which does a `findOne` on the current user and updates the `Connects` collection. Here it's safe to read the `services` data because the code is running on the server.

**if the services info is needed on the client (e.g. a photo)**

You'll need to copy the data from `services` into a safe field like `profile`. You could do this either when the user [creates her account](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser) or whenever she [logs in](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_onlogin).